# What function in ArcGIS Pro Python replaces the ArcMap data frame method zoomToSelectedFeatures()?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, select, zoom

What function in ArcGIS Pro Python replaces the ArcMap data frame method `zoomToSelectedFeatures()`?

I already tried other solutions (getLayerExtend for Layout), but didn't work.

```py
##SNIPPET CODE
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=pipeFeat, selection_type="NEW_SELECTION", where_clause=exp)
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a direct equivalent in ArcGIS Pro.  However, the code below is similar to what I do for zooming to a list of layers' extents, taking into account selected features.  It's a fairly tedious process.  Note the optional `selection_only = True` to include only selected features when determining the extent (`True` is the default, so is not actually required in the code... I've just included it here to make it clear).

Note that this code snippet includes one variation of how to define the list of layers of interest (ie, `theLayers`).  There may be other ways, depending on your needs.

The first part of this code is just to obtain a handle to the active map view OR to the map frame within the active layout view (ie, so it works whether the active view is a map view or a layout view).  The last bit calculates the extent to zoom to and then does the actual zooming.

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
activeView = aprx.activeView
try:
    activeView.camera.getExtent()
    activeMapView = activeView
except:
    try:
        activeLayoutMapFrames = activeView.listElements("mapframe_element")
        if len(activeLayoutMapFrames) == 1:
            activeMapView = activeLayoutMapFrames[0]
    except:
        activeMapView = None

map = aprx.activeMap
theLayers = [l for l in map.listLayers() if l.isFeatureLayer and l.getSelectionSet() is not None]
zoomExtent = None

if activeMapView is not None:
    for lyr in theLayers:
        layerExtent = activeMapView.getLayerExtent(lyr, selection_only=True)
        if layerExtent:
            if zoomExtent is None:
                zoomExtent = layerExtent
            else:
                zoomExtent.XMin = min([zoomExtent.XMin, layerExtent.XMin])
                zoomExtent.XMax = max([zoomExtent.XMax, layerExtent.XMax])
                zoomExtent.YMin = min([zoomExtent.YMin, layerExtent.YMin])
                zoomExtent.YMax = max([zoomExtent.YMax, layerExtent.YMax])
    if zoomExtent is not None:
        activeMapView.camera.setExtent(zoomExtent)
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the right code for me. I was surprised how complex this zoomToSelectedFeatures() function became to be used from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro.

Below is the code that is working for me:

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
df = aprx.listMaps('*')[0]
av = aprx.activeView
lyr = "Pipes" #(layer name)

for i in df.listLayers():
    if i.name == lyr:
        lyr = i #(become a layer object)

exp = r"PIPEID = 'PIPE41000'"
selection = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr, "NEW_SELECTION", exp)
ext = av.getLayerExtent(lyr,True)
ext.XMin = ext.XMin + 50
ext.YMin = ext.YMin + 50
ext.XMax = ext.XMax - 50
ext.YMax = ext.YMax - 50
av.camera.setExtent(ext)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to select and zoom to only 1 single feature in 1 single layer (which you did not specify in your original question).  That makes things a bit easier.  The function in your original question will zoom to the extent of multiple features in multiple layers (which is also what my answer does, which is why it's code is more complex).

Comment: Note that your code may not work if your active view is a layout view, even if it includes a map frame.  See may answer for a way of dealing with this issue (if it matters in your situation).

Comment: Also, see @Clubdebambos answer for some ways of simplifying your code.  In particular, you can use @Clubdebambos example of the `listLayers()` call to avoid the need the to use a `for` loop (not to be confused with `listLayouts()`).

Comment: Last comment on this code (for now?)...  The `selection = ` at the beginning of the `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_managment` line is unnecessary.  You assign to the `selection` variable, but you never use that variable anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
## access the aprx
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")

## access the layout of interest
lyt = aprx.listLayouts("LAYOUT_NAME")[0]

## access the map frame
mf = lyt.listElements('MAPFRAME_ELEMENT', "MAPFRAME_NAME")[0]

## access the layer to zoom to
lyr = mf.map.listLayers("LAYER_NAME")[0]

## get bounding box of layer/selection
bbox = arcpy.management.MinimumBoundingGeometry(lyr, "memory\\bbox", "ENVELOPE", "ALL")

## get the extent of the bbox
extent = [row[0].extent for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(bbox, "SHAPE@")][0]

## set the camera to the extent
mf.camera.setExtent(extent)

## delete the bbox from memory workspace
arcpy.management.Delete(bbox)
```